Is it possible to implement a generalised REST Api call method with Yii2's Client class if I want to set postfields for requests which are POST?
I am trying to implement a unified method for calling a REST API in Yii2, using the Client class.
The method receives $method, $action, $headers = [], , $data = [], $postFields = [] as parameters. The request creation looks like:
$request = $client->createRequest()
            ->setMethod($method)
            ->setUrl("$this->accessPoint/$action")
            ->setData($data)
            ->setFormat(Client::FORMAT_JSON)
            ->addHeaders($headers)
            ->setOptions([
                'timeout' => 60,
            ]);

For some requests with $method = 'POST', I also want to include a postFields in the request, as in the following curl example in the documentation of the API:
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => //url_to_my_api,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => \\some_json_formatted_array_of_params,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Authorization: Basic REPLACE_BASIC_AUTH",
        "Message-Reference: SOME_STRING_VALUE",
        "Message-Reference-Date: SOME_STRING_VALUE",
        "Plugin-Name: SOME_STRING_VALUE",
        "Plugin-Version: SOME_STRING_VALUE",
        "Shipping-System-Platform-Name: SOME_STRING_VALUE",
        "Shipping-System-Platform-Version: SOME_STRING_VALUE",
        "Webstore-Platform-Name: SOME_STRING_VALUE",
        "Webstore-Platform-Version: SOME_STRING_VALUE",
        "content-type: application/json"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

If this unified method receives $postFields as an empty array, I don't want to include $postFields in the request.
Is it possible to do this with this unified approach, by calling a method like "setPostFields" (I haven't found looking on the internet) after createRequest if !empty($postFields)?
If not, what would you recommend for this unified approach to REST API calling?
More generally, I would also like to know if you have any reference which makes clear the correspondence between these parameters in the curl_setopt_array function, on the one hand, and how to set them inside the Request class in Yii2, on the other. I have searched a fair amount but didn't find anything. As I'm relatively new to Yii2 and to working with APIs as well, I might just not know what to look for.

You can't use Content-Type: application/json with mixed content

@SIZE could you please elaborate on what "mixed content" means and what makes the context mixed here? As I said, I'm not familiar with these things. The template I have given is the exact one that the API gives for requests. Specifically, https://developer.dhl.com/api-reference/dhl-express-mydhl-api#operations-tag-pickup
in the POST request to /shipments.

your first code example didn't work?
